# Unable to load libcomposite.ko using insmod in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to load libcomposite.ko on my Ubuntu host, but it fails. I am using the command:

```
sudo insmod /lib/modules/5.19.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/gadget/libcomposite.ko
```

I also used `modprobe --force` but it returns FATAL Error. Can you help me? I am trying to make gadget driver running on BBB work.

```
modprobe --force-vermagic /lib/modules/5.19.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/gadget/libcomposite.ko
modprobe: FATAL: Module /lib/modules/5.19.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/gadget/libcomposite.ko not found in directory /lib/modules/5.19.0-38-generic
```

```
sudo insmod /lib/modules/5.19.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/gadget/libcomposite.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/5.19.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/gadget/libcomposite.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

Comment: where did you get the module? you might need to build it for your kernel

Comment: Check the kernel log messages (for example by running `sudo dmesg`) after attempting to load the module.

Comment: Hi Ian - Thanks for responding. This is what dmesg says for insmod:

Comment: Hi @PrateekSonthalia Try,  Just "modprobe libcomposite" . If it fails, Please share the error logs printed on the console and also from the dmesg.

Comment: In the first case you asked for non-existing module (it may be built-in, though). In the second -- the module requires symbol which is absent in your kernel.

Comment: Thanks Thushi... modprobbe libcomposite.ko is working.